# Advance function pointer?

Tags: c++

Is the following possible in c++?

```
int do_stuff(int one, int two)
{
    ...
    return ...;
}

int main()
{
    void *ptr = &do_stuff(6, 7);//DON'T CALL THE FUNCTION, just store a pointer

    cout << *ptr;//call the function from the pointer without having to pass the arguments again
}
```

I know this can be done with classes, but is it possible the way I am trying to do it?

Comment: functor can be a choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not like that. There is nothing in the code

```
void *ptr = &do_stuff(6, 7);
```

that makes it parse like you want. I'm unsure if it would parse *at all*, if you can take the address of the return value. Taking the address of a function is basically a no-op, but function pointers don't convert to `void *` so it has problems anyway.

You need more magic, like C++11's [lambda closures](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html).

I'm no C++11 programmer, but I guess your code would look like:

```
int main(void)
{
  auto func = [] () { do_stuff(6, 7); };
  func();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aha, I see how lambda can be useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well with c++11 and a little magic from std::function and std::bind you can.

```
std::function<int()> f = std::bind(&do_stuff,6,7);
std::cout << f();
```

Comment: It's better to avoid the overhead of `std::function` unless you need type erasure. If it's only used locally, I'd declare `auto f` to give it the callable type returned by `bind`.